# Code wont multiply integers, Error invalid operands to binary + (have 'int *' and 'int *')

Tags: c

i have this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() 
{
    char firstName[99], middleName[99], lastName[99];
    int  hourPay[99], hourWeek[99], taxRate[99], grossSal[99], taxDed[99], netSal[99];

    printf("Enter your first name:");
    scanf("%s", &firstName);
    printf("Enter your middle initial:");
    scanf("%s", &middleName);
    printf("Enter your last name:");
    scanf("%s", &lastName);
    printf("Enter your hourly rate of pay:\n");
    scanf("%d", &hourPay);
    printf("Enter hours worked per week:\n");
    scanf("%d", &hourWeek);
    printf("Enter your tax rate:");
    scanf("%d", taxRate);
    grossSal = hourPay * hourWeek;
    printf("%d", grossSal);
    system("pause");

}
```

Everything was working fine till i got to line 21, i added in the "int" line after it stopped running to try and differentiate the text inputs from the number inputs but that didnt help,and i am stuck language is C

Comment: `hourPay` and `hourWeek` are arrays. You can't multiply arrays directly in C.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int` variables are actually arrays of `int`, and it doesn't make sense to do multiplication on arrays.

Change your definitions to:

```
int  hourPay, hourWeek, taxRate, grossSal, taxDed, netSal;
```

And change this:

```
scanf("%d", taxRate);
```

To this:

```
scanf("%d", &taxRate);
```

Also, you should remove the `&` when reading in strings, since the `%s` format specifier expects a `char *` (which `char` array decays to) and not a pointer to an array which is what you're passing in now.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring int arrays by doing `int hourPay[99]`. If you are only taking one input from the user, remove the `[99]` from the ints. Then it should work. If you are taking multiple inputs of each variable, you'll have to reference a specific member in the array you want to use.